# Sitecore restart now showing old information

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Good day – We rebranded our site back in June, with new images, CSS and a thorough review of the site content to replace instances of the old name with the new .  After rollout, everything was fine - site was stable and we were able to move forward with standard maintenance stuff - updating, archiving, etc.

We had to restart our production site server this morning and we just noticed that the SC content on the site is now all showing the old information. I have checked the SC backend and all of the content has the old information and is missing recently added items. It is like SC rolled back a month.

We are currently on Sitecore 7.2, hosted internally on a Server2008R2 Windows box, IIS 7.5, 4.0 .NET framework.

How can something like this happen by rebooting the server? We are working with our third-party provider, but figured I would also post here to see if anyone else has run into this issue.

Comment: Not a Sitecore issue. Try checking your connection strings are correct and not pointed to an old backup.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @jammykam,  We checked not only the Sitecore connection strings (which had not changed), but the DB itself.  The two DBs supporting SC had been rolled back somehow.  We did a restore from the previous days' backups and were back in business.  Now we are trying to figure out how it happened, be it SC or DB, and how to prevent it happening again.

Comment: I can't see this being a Sitecore issue, at least not by default, there is nothing in the CMS that works at that level on SQL Server. Good luck in tracking it down.

Comment: @chipsterva69: You may want to answer your own question here when you find out the reason for the SQL rollback, but Sitecore itself does not roll back the SQL server databases. Your site can run on cache until the reboot, but even then IIS would recycle it's memory eventually so your window of investigation should be small. Likely, databases were restored to backup during a maintenance window, possibly because of request made or a failed windows patch that triggered rollback procedures.